# Property "x" is missing in type 'y' but required in type "z" during fetch request/return

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I have an interface setup for use by an async function:

```
interface PostScriptTagResponse {
  script_tag : {
    readonly id : number
    , src : string
    , event : string
    , readonly created_at : string
    , readonly updated_at : string
    , display_scope? : string
  }
}

protected async createScriptTag(): Promise<PostScriptTagResponse|null> {
    try {
      const data: PostScriptTagResponse = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
        method: 'post'
        , headers: {
          "X-Shopify-Access-Token": this.generalToken
          , "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        , body: {
          script_tag : {
            src: `${this.serverHost}/server/frontEndScriptControl.js`
            , event: "onload"
            , display_scope: "online_store"
          }
        }
      }).json();

      return data.script_tag;
      // Property "script_tag" is missing in type {detailed interface spec here} 
      // but required in type "PostScriptTagResponse"
    }
    catch (e) {
      // removed
    }    
  }
```

I've relooked at the above and think the format is correct, is this wrong? Here is an example response I expect to receive from this fetch request:

```
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/scripttag#create-2019-10
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
{
  "script_tag": {
    "id": 870402694,
    "src": "https://djavaskripped.org/fancy.js",
    "event": "onload",
    "created_at": "2019-10-16T16:14:18-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-16T16:14:18-04:00",
    "display_scope": "all"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within those 3 lines:

```
protected async createScriptTag(): Promise<PostScriptTagResponse|null> {
      const data: PostScriptTagResponse = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
      return data.script_tag;
```

You are awaiting `data`, which is from type `PostScriptTagResponse`. Then you return a property (`script_tag`) of it, which is very much likely not again from type `PostScriptTagResponse`. But your function signature says you want to return a `PostScriptTagResponse`.

So either change the function signature to somehting like this:

```
protected async createScriptTag(): Promise<YourScriptTagType|null> {
```

Or return the response as is and use the `.script_tag` property within the consumer.

```
 protected async createScriptTag(): Promise<PostScriptTagResponse|null> {
      return await fetch(fetchUrl, { //...
```

Since your function is called `createScriptTag` you most likely want to do the first approach